# Implementing ERC-20 token as main payment method on website - hiring

Tags: erc-20, gas

I own a content writing self-service platform and want to start my own ERC-20 token that becomes the main payment method.

The process currently works like this (with fiat):

1) Client pays through Paypal in dollars
2) Client places an order and funds get frozen
3) Writer accepts job and submits work
4) Client approves the work and funds are released (to the writer)

I want to change this to:

1) Client buys tokens at the platform or at an external exchange
2) 0.1% from funds that client sends to the platform are deducted
2a) This 0.1% ends up in platforms account to take care of gas payments
3) Client places order, funds go to escrow account
4) Writer accepts job / submits work
5) Client approves work and tokens are released to writer
6) Writer cashes out their tokens at external exchange or keeps them.

However I have no idea how to make this work so I'm looking for someone that can help me with this and sent me a quote.

I understand this is perhaps not the way this exchange section works but I figured this is the best place to get started.

I'm familiar with PHP and a tiny bit of jQuery but that's about it. The platform itself is 99.9% PHP.

Comment: I am not aware of any service providing token payments yet as the writing of this. This website is generally for Q&A and this reads more like a hiring post. I suggest you post this to https://jobs.ethercasts.com/ instead

Comment: Thanks Mikko, I wasn't aware of a job site at ethercasts so will repost it there!

Comment: No problem, hopefully something will pop up soon to address this problem. Generally it is not a great programming exercise, as handling token transactions is easier than handling ETH transactions themselves.

Comment: I'm a bit of a trial & error coder in PHP, looking up tons of code at the main stackexchange, and I had the platform developed by others so I had a ton of example code to teach myself and reuse the code. However with crypto everything is brand new, with few example codes available. I don't have an idea in which language its written so although it looks like it can't be that complicated I don't even know where to get started. Perhaps I'll just have to create a token first and simply take it from there, and see if I can fit the pieces together.

Comment: Interesting you said it's not a great programming exercise, still I get contacted by people that quote me 10000 British Pounds, and other absurd amounts for something that should be rather straight forward.